# prestashop 1.5 core file overwrite

Tags: php, prestashop

I want to overwrite prestashop 1.5 core file `FrontController.php` to overwrite from `override\classes\controller` folder but it didn't load my overwrite folder file.

```
<?php

    class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
    {

    /* Display a specific page if the user country is not allowed */
        protected function displayRestrictedCountryPage() {

        }
    }
```

Any body have idea how to over write core prestashop file in 1.5

I also follow this [document](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors) but no way to solve.

Answer (score 6):

Prestashop 1.5.x automatically merge default override file and you custom file on `module::install()` function. You just need to create a correct hierarchy in your module folder: `modules/your_package/override/classes/controller/FrontController.php` with your custom functional. 
If you don't have an extension and want to add override manually - you need to change the file `override/classes/controller/FrontController.php`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the **class_index.php** under */cache* folder.

It carries Presta's Class & Controller file details. Once you delete and reload the page, prestashop will automatically generate the file with latest changes.

Comment: I had exactly this problem. Everything was correct in my code, but I couldn't see changes because of cache

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be, that one of your functions which contains `parent::nameOfFunction`, You should replace parent in the function by the inheritance of the parent function you want to override.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're trying to override is called in the core function init(). what you should do is to override both init() and displayRestrictedCountryPage(). Then inside the init function use Controller::init() instead of parent::init()

Answer (score 0):

After override whatever you want don"t forget to delete the cache folder contents and recreate them because that lost my time for a while till found the solution [here](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/238197-solved-overrides-not-working-anymore-in-154/)